# Basic Syntax Error Unfixable?

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors

```
   int ATTRIBUTES;
   ATTRIBUTES* addRelation(char*,char*,ATTRIBUTES*);
   void nattr(ATTRIBUTES*);
   void tuplelen(ATTRIBUTES*);
   void infattr(char*,ATTRIBUTES*);
   void addValues(ATTRIBUTES*,char*);
   int count(VALUES*);
   void project(ATTRIBUTES*,char*);
   void select(char*,char*,char*,ATTRIBUTES*);
   int inStringArray(char[]**,int,char*);
```

At first I thought it was a point issue that I lacked declaration so I just declared ATTRIBUTES with or without the declaration it still gives me the errors below

Does anyone see something I'm missing or is it not possible for my program to work this way ? Below you can see the lines in which each error is occurring I'm pretty sure my syntax is correct so I'm stuck on stupid as to whats missing .. Anyone see something I don't ?

[update from comment]

```
prototypes.h:2:11: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or 'attribute' before '' token prototypes.h:3:22: error: expected ')' before '' token     
prototypes.h:4:25: error: expected ')' before '*' token prototypes.h:5:20: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before
```

Comment: prototypes.h:2:11: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
prototypes.h:3:22: error: expected ')' before '*' token
prototypes.h:4:25: error: expected ')' before '*' token
prototypes.h:5:20: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before

Comment: Those are the errors

Comment: Do you create the `type` `ATTRIBUTES` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Just the declaration at the top, is there a more specific declaration I need

Comment: What's line 2 and 4?

Comment: ATTRIBUTES* addRelation(char*,char*,ATTRIBUTES*);

   void tuplelen(ATTRIBUTES*);

Comment: in general, for good programing practice and for readability, variable names should not be all capitals, rather use 'camel case' for variables and function names.  Use all capitals for #define names and constant names.

Comment: 'select' is a system library function name.  the code should 'never' try to replace system function names, especially when the relevant library is being referenced.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your code, you want ATTRIBUTES to be synonymous with int. Assuming this, rather than writing

```
int ATTRIBUTES;
```

which will declare a variable of type int, named ATTRIBUTES, try either

```
typedef int ATTRIBUTES;
```

which says "whenever ATTRIBUTES is used as a type, it means int instead", or

```
#define ATTRIBUTES int
```

which is slightly cruder, and replaces all instances of ATTRIBUTES with int, textually, before compilation.

Without looking at the whole file, I cannot diagnose any other errors you might be having, however that should fix at least a good proportion of the errors you're seeing.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help